# Worthwhile to convert ArrayList to array for performance?

Tags: arrays, sorting, arraylist

I recently discovered the ArrayList's "toArray() : Object[]" method and I wonder if I should leverage that to increase performance.

I know the ArrayList is a more expensive than an Object[] array, but it of course is more convenient since it automatically resizes. But I figure maybe if I use the ArrayList to build my object list, I can turn it into an Object[] array when I do the more intense data operations.

Is it good practice to turn ArrayList into any array Object[] after the ArrayList is finished building? Sometimes if I am looping through 200K object ArrayLists and comparing it against another ArrayList of objects, it takes awhile. Would I benefit performance-wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should never make assumptions about performance. You need to measure it. I've just proven my "feeling" wrong. I was quite sure that the performance of `ArrayList` vs `Object[]` would be very much comparable. With `initialCapacity` set, `ArrayList` is just a simple wrapper on an array. And those wrapper methods are surely inlined by the JVM.

Turns out I was wrong. I wrote a [simple test](https://gist.github.com/rzymek/7467855/2a11dd7560c2d4e727c3a7aab397e91eb68d695c) to get some real numbers. And on my machine (Oracle Java 7 64bit, Linux) the numbers are:

```
ArrayList write: 105.8ms
String[]  write:  39.8ms

ArrayList read:   64.1ms
String[]  read:   40.9ms
```

So `ArrayList` is about 100% slower on `set()` and 50% slower on `get()`.

That was without autoboxing kicking in. I also [run a test](https://gist.github.com/rzymek/7467855/ea25ea9f1a89089d8761e761ca96c5c773754477) on `ArrayList<Integer>` vs `int[]`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> write: 2660.0ms
int[]              write:   27.5ms

ArrayList<Integer> read:    59.5ms
int[]              read:    20.2ms
```

GC did not run during the `String[]` test, but during `int[]` test it run about 25 times.

Nevertheless copying `ArrayList` to `Object[]` just to sort does not make sense:

```
14.98ms  Collections.sort(list)
15.32ms  Arrays.sort(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete previous anwsers, when performance matters, it is also a good practice to look at the real implementation 
of [ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java) and analyse the particular operations you will use the most. You can look at the overhead in get and set operations (here overhead is induced by type genericity, range checking and func call). This will help you to decides if it worse the work. 
(As a general remark , do not optimize everywhere, but only the few points  where  it really matters)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the situation. Sometimes it's better to convert it, otherwise it isn't. You have to weigh the pros and cons against eachother - if you have to do a lot of actions on the object than an ArrayList can be the best solution. Surely because other people in your project might depend on an ArrayList.

Otherwise, if you know that developping the application won't be harmed by using Array[] (meaning no one else depends on it, and you don't mind doing some extra work writing your own sort etc) than an Array[] can be the best choice.

Array[] = more performant for the program
ArrayList -> Easier to write / Saves time.

It all depends on what  you want to do :)